# How can to insert update and delete records in a csv file obtained with OpenFileDialogue as datasource in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

I am trying to come up with a solution which reads CSV files and edit them from open file dialogue

I'm able to read the file and display it to the data grid view but can only edit or update from the data grid, not with textboxes and button.

```
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            DataTable table = CSVReader.ReadCSVFile(dialog.FileName, true);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }
```

assist with the syntax for editing CSV files

Comment: Textboxes must exist in the form and be bound to the DG either manually or using the datasource property. Your code does not show any example of textbox.

Comment: You'll have to use [Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding) if you want to allow a control other than the DGV to update your data. In the form of `Control.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Property", source, "Data Column", options));`. Use a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource) to *connect* you DataTable to the controls that share this functionality. It'll make it easier to handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to read this question a few times before I fully understood what you are asking for.  As I understand it, you want to do Insert, Update, and Delete operations in a DataGridView, and then write the results to a CSV file, right.  You don't want to do the operations directly on the CSV file, right.  With that clarified, try the script below and feed back.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            txtFile.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            BindData(txtFile.Text);
        }

        private void BindData(string filePath)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            if (lines.Length > 0)
            {
                //first line to create header
                string firstLine = lines[0];
                string[] headerLabels = firstLine.Split(',');
                foreach (string headerWord in headerLabels)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headerWord));
                }
                //For Data
                for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] dataWords = lines[i].Split(',');
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    int columnIndex = 0;
                    foreach (string headerWord in headerLabels)
                    {
                        dr[headerWord] = dataWords[columnIndex++];
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Build the CSV file data as a Comma separated string.
                string csv = string.Empty;

                //Add the Header row for CSV file.
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    csv += column.HeaderText + ',';
                }
                //Add new line.
                csv += "\r\n";

                //Adding the Rows

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (cell.Value != null)
                        {
                            //Add the Data rows.
                            csv += cell.Value.ToString().TrimEnd(',').Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                        }
                        // break;
                    }
                    //Add new line.
                    csv += "\r\n";
                }

                //Exporting to CSV.
                string folderPath = "C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\";
                if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
                }
                File.WriteAllText(folderPath + "test.csv", csv);
                MessageBox.Show("");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]